# How to create procedure with multiple string select query in sql?

Tags: sql

I want to create procedure with multiple string select query.I want to insert data to table variable and join that temp table with other table.
I don't want to create temp table as real tables. I want to insert data to memory temp table.

Here is my procedure,

```
  CREATE PROCEDURE sp_TempBatch
  AS
  DECLARE  @TempBatchSerial TABLE
      (
        ID          int,
        Name        nvarchar(200),
        StockType   nvarchar(50),
        ItemNo      nvarchar(50)
      )

  DECLARE   @TempQuery   as nvarchar(MAX)='',
            @VendorQuery as nvarchar(MAX)=''
 BEGIN

    SET @TempQuery='SELECT ID,Name,' 

    IF StockType = '1'  
    BEGIN
        SET @TempQuery += ' ''Batch'' as StockType,'
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @TempQuery += ' ''Serial''  as StockType,'
    END

    SET @TempQuery += 'ItemNo INTO @TempBatchSerial
                       FROM Stock'

    EXEC (@TempQuery)

    SET @VendorQuery+=' SELECT @TempBatchSerial.* FROM @TempBatchSerial 
                        INNER JOIN Vendor 
                        ON @TempBatchSerial.ID = Vendor.ID 
                        INNER JOIN Partner 
                        ON Vendor.parentid = Partner.syskey' 
    EXEC (@VendorQuery)
 END
```

When execute procedure show error message of Must declare the table variable "@TempBatchSerial"

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is far from ANSI SQL comlinant.)

Answer (score 0):

You have to refer to @tempBatchSerial via an Alias 
That's the only way @tempTables can be referred or linked to.

```
SELECT T.* FROM @TempBatchSerial T 
                    INNER JOIN Vendor 
                    ON T.ID = Vendor.ID 
                    INNER JOIN Partner 
                    ON Vendor.parentid = Partner.syskey
```

If that doesn't work you can try to put the @tempTable in the @vendorQuery text.